# How to keep transparency when scale png file with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to scale my PNG icon, by using below command:
ffmpeg -i sticker.png -vf scale=300:300 out.png
The output has correct resolution as I expected but the problem is transparency parts become white background.

Could someone give me a solution for this.

Thank you so much.

[Before scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMt8W.png)

[After scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4vy9.png)

Comment: I can't duplicate the issue. Please show the complete console output from your command.

Comment: Hi, I fixed the issue by add --enable-swscale-alpha when building ffmpeg. Thanks for your time ^^.

Comment: You shouldn't need to have to manually enable that. Default is enabled.