# Scaling transparent image with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, images

I am trying to add an overlay with transparent pixels to a video.

When only using the overlay filter the image is correctly added on top of the video.

```
-filter_complex = "[video][image]overlay=128:128[output]"
```

The problem I have is when trying to scale the overlay image like this:

```
-filter_complex = "[image]scale=64:64[scaledImage];[video][scaledImage]overlay128:128[output]"
```

The transparent pixels of the image become white.

I am using the latest build found [here](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/).

The only related question I have found is [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1148879/how-to-keep-transparency-when-scale-png-file-with-ffmpeg).

Thanks.

**Edit.**

I have found the problem. I was using the `-deinterlace` flag poorly, applying it to the image. I have replaced the `-deinterlace` flag with the `yadif` filter. My filter complex looks like this:

```
-filter_complex = "[video]yadif[deinterlacedVideo];[image]scale=64:64[scaledImage];[deinterlacedVideo][scaledImage]overlay128:128[output]"
```

Comment: Quoting the comment from the other question, “please show the complete console output from your command”. Ideally supply a sample image so we can test.

Comment: Now that you found a solution you can add it as an answer to your question.